# Is it possible to avoid execution of check function if available in module while importing it

Tags: python, python-import, pypi, rar

To be specific,
PyPi package **rarfile** has `_check_unrar_tool()` function that runs on import. I don't want it run while importing, because it throws permission error in certain boxes.
I cant modify the package at my place due to certain restrictions.

So, as in this scenario, is it possible to ignore `_check_unrar_tool()` call and import successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats stopping you from going into `yourpythonfolder/Lib` to change it though? To me that seems like the easiest way compared to other alternatives. You could also instead download `rarfile` on a different computer with elevated privileges, identify the relevant code files and copy/paste write your own custom package that does not run the `_check_unrar_tool()` call

Comment: Well, lets say there is different team that deals with installing python packages to boxes and I just use'em ..  I think we could consider a generic scenario where any module might have check function running and we might need to avoid it for our environment  when we are doing partial import ....@ycx

Comment: no offense intended, but why don't you `try: catch` the permission error ?

Comment: import fails when it raises exception. My need is a successful import in any case ..

Comment: @reportgunner makes a fair point. However I am under the impression that once a try block is exited because of an exception, there is no way back in?

Comment: what operating system is having these permission errors ? Linux or windows ?

Comment: Linux. Actually this issue is addressed here but not applied to package https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/Paddle/issues/4180

Actually I was just wandering if there is any way to address this as a generic case ...

Comment: Generic answer: no, it's not possible to avoid running module-level initialization code when the module is imported for the 1st time. The only way is to edit the source code. Either of the module or of Python itself.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the `rarfile` package, more specifically the `_check_unrar_tool()` just expects a return code of `0` from the `unrar` command.

If you can somehow check if the `unrar` command works **before** importing the package, you can *substitute* it for *something else* that returns `0` and you can get away without messing with the package.